# Is there a better way to make this mysql query using inner join commands?

Tags: mysql, inner-join, relationships

In my database I have several tables with "many to many" relationships referencing one another, and the way I was taught to make this queries was through embedded queries. 
I've been reading about "many to many" relationships, and how to query them using "Inner Join" but, I don't seem to be able to find queries that fit what I'm looking for, and since my database will work with very big tables I don't want my code to have performance issues.

```
SELECT salones.idSalon, 
       salones.Lat, 
       salones.Long, 
       recursos.idRecurso, 
       recursos.Recurso
FROM salones, 
     recursos, 
     salones_has_recursos
WHERE salones_has_recursos.salones_idSalon=salones.idSalon 
  AND salones_has_recursos.recursos_idRecurso=recursos.idRecurso 
  AND recursos.idRecurso IN (SELECT idRecurso
                             FROM salones_has_recursos
                             WHERE idRecurso IN (SELECT idRecurso
                                                 FROM recursos
                                                 WHERE recurso = 'Audiovisual'
                                                )
                            )
```

I know having embedded queries is a performance killer, but this is the only way I could figure how to get the info I need from the table. Does anyone know how to get this same result using "inner join" commands?

[The resulting table should look a little like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oayo0.png) 
[This is the all the data content of the tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gimdY.png)

Comment: sqlfiddle.com some test data and show desired output, please.

Comment: just say no to "comma joins"

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you a starter in the hopes that you can figure out how it works:

This:

```
select idRecurso from salones_has_recursos where idRecurso in
(select idRecurso from recursos where recursos = 'Audiovisual');
```

Becomes:

```
select 
  s.idRecurso 
from 
  salones_has_recursos s
  inner join recursos r
    on s.idRecurso = r.idRecurso
    where r.recursos = 'Audiovisual';
```

I can't guarantee it will work sans a means to test, but I think this is your full solution:

```
SELECT 
   s.idSalon, 
   s.Lat, 
   s.Long, 
   r.idRecurso, 
   r.Recurso
FROM 
   salones s
   inner join recursos r
     on s.idRecurso = r.idRecurso
     and r.recursos = 'Audiovisual'
   inner join salones_has_recursos sr
     on sr.salones_idSalon=s.idSalon
     and sr.recursos_idRecurso=r.idRecurso;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one, it's hard to test without sqlfiddle but try this and see.

```
SELECT salones.idSalon, 
       salones.Lat, 
       salones.Long, 
       recursos.idRecurso, 
       recursos.Recurso
FROM salones 
     INNER JOIN salones_has_recursos ON salones_has_recursos.salones_idSalon=salones.idSalon 
     INNER JOIN recursos ON salones_has_recursos.recursos_idRecurso=recursos.idRecurso
     AND recursos.idRecursor = salones_has_recursors.idRecurso
     AND recursos.recurso = 'Audiovisual'
```

Answer (score 0):

I *think* this is the equivalent JOIN query. The join of r1, shr1, and r2 seem a more than a little "off" to me; I'm not sure if that is because of an error in how I converted it, or if it was carried over from the original.

```
SELECT s2.idSalon, 
       s2.Lat, 
       s2.Long, 
       r2.idRecurso, 
       r2.Recurso
FROM recursos AS r1
INNER JOIN salones_has_recursos AS shr1 ON r1.idRecurso = shr1.idRecurso
INNER JOIN recurso AS r2 ON shr1.idRecurso = r2.idRecurso
INNER JOIN salones_has_recursos AS shr2 ON r2.idRecurso = shr2.recursos_idRecurso
INNER JOIN salones AS s2 ON shr2.salones_idSalon=s2.idSalon 
WHERE r1.recurso = 'Audiovisual'
;
```

It's also not 100% guaranteed to give the same results as there is sort of an implicit `DISTINCT` in `IN` operations.

---

By "off" I mean this:

```
recursos.idRecurso IN (SELECT idRecurso
                             FROM salones_has_recursos
                             WHERE idRecurso IN (SELECT idRecurso
                                                 FROM recursos
                                                 WHERE recurso = 'Audiovisual'
                                                )
                            )
```

appears to be equivalent to this:
`recursos.recurso = 'Audiovisual'`